# Logstash 2.0 to Elasticsearch 1.7.0 Error Using Transport Client

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-configuration

I'm using the elasticsearch_java output plugin in Logstash 2.0 to push to a cluster running 1.7.0. According to the documentation this plugin should work just fine against any cluster running ES 1.0 or greater.

However I'm getting this error on the ES client node I'm pushing to and nothing else.

```
 Message not fully read (request) for requestId [0], action [cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness], readerIndex [50] vs expected [51]; resetting
```

Anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699552/upgrade-elasticsearch-1-4-1-to-2-0-same-config-fails  If that isn't it, could you maybe post the rest of the exception backtrace as it might be usefull.

Comment: Agreed, this is most certainly the exact same issue, i.e. your `elasticsearch_java` logstash process is talking to your ES cluster via TCP with a different Java version than the one your ES is running on. You can fix this by simply using the `elasticsearch` output instead, which uses HTTP instead of TCP and is also faster.

Comment: Can't use the HTTP client for some dumb reasons I won't get into. However I've swapped the java version to the same as the cluster and it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue. Both are Running 1.8_60